# Python path manipulation

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using GAE and webapp2 to create a simple PM application.

This is part of my code for adding a task, associated to my project.

```
class AddTask(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
    def get(self):
        project_id = self.request.path.split('/')[-1]
        print project_id
        project = Project.get_by_id(int(project_id))
        print project
        template_values = {
            'project': project,
            'project_id': project_id
            }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../templates/project-task-add.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

The url is handled this way `http://localhost:8080/projects/5812155903377408/tasks/add`

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the project_id right. Split function only splits into everything after the last slash and everything behind it, so I cannot use split. Is there any other way of handling this, or do I have to restructure my `main.py`? And is putting a key id in the url a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to extract parameters by splitting URLs. You should let the webapp2 route matcher do the work, and pass the parameters to your handler.

[The documentation](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html) is fairly comprehensive, but to summarise for your case:

```
class AddTask(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
    def get(self, project_id):
        project = Project.get_by_id(int(project_id))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ...
    (r'/projects/(\d+)/tasks/add', AddTask),
])
```