# GAE wrong URI routing

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, routes

Here is my main.py and I would like to extract everything after the equals sign.

The example url would be
`/loggedin?frob=72157645687641769-37c9ec9b8fb35d48-125787757`
and I would like to extract `72157645687641769-37c9ec9b8fb35d48-125787757`

```
import webapp2
from flickr.views import Flickr, FlickrAuthorized


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/index', Flickr),
    (r'/loggedin?frob=<:((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))>', FlickrAuthorized)
], debug=True)
```

My handler has the following class:

```
class FlickrAuthorized(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self, frob):
     print frob    
     //code
```

Comment: Something like `import re
p = re.compile(ur'=[\w-]+')
test_str = u"/loggedin?frob=72157645687641769-37c9ec9b8fb35d48-125787757" 
re.match(p, test_str)` The regex here is `=[\w-]+` Test it out [here](http://regex101.com/r/aR5eD9/1)

Comment: doesn't Flickr has a flickr.auth.getfrob?  I'm trying to see what you're doing and if all you need is after the =, getfrob would work.

or I would use self.request and get the frob parameter.... how is the url passed to your app?

Comment: @Julldar I am using an API Kit for python, it has to redirect me to my app after I grant access to it, if I have understood the documentation well. Should I avoid the kit? The application goes to /index, after I redirect to authorization page provided by the documentation, I redirect back to ?loggedin?frob=frobvalue and try to get the frob parameter so that i can do the second "dance" of authentication as mentioned in the documents. http://stuvel.eu/media/flickrapi-docs/documentation/

Comment: @skamazin That includes the equals sign, but how do I put that in the webapp2 routing as the question mark earlier is most likely causing trouble?

Comment: @BorkoKovacev Check out Greg's answer below. Accept it if it worked for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should access the query-string parts from within your handler, not by matching them in the URL:

```
class FlickrAuthorized(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      frob = self.request.get('frob')
      # code...


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/index', Flickr),
    (r'/loggedin', FlickrAuthorized)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for coming to the rescue again. The FlickrAPI once the request has been made, adds ?frob=value to the provided callback url only, in my case /loggedin?frob=value. So how would I implement what you have suggested? I am using the logic from the question I have had earlier this month. Sorry I am a beginner and I might not have all the proper knowledge, so thank you for your patience. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608265/python-path-manipulation/24608404#24608404

Comment: Capturing patterns from URLs makes sense if you want to match against the path part (/foo/bar), but the query-string (?key1=value1&key2=value2) will be parsed for you, and made accessible as "self.request.get('key1')" from inside the handler-method. The webapp2 docs describe this too, it might be clearer: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html